# SQL server Temp table with joins inside other select

Tags: sql-server, subquery, union, temp-tables, sql-server-2014-express

I have the following structure:

```
Create @temp
Select ...inser...into @temp where ...

(select ... from @temp
Join tblA where ... )
UNION
(Select ... from @temp
join tblB where ... )
```

After build above table I need to be able to perform WHERE, JOINS, ...

Something like:

```
Select ... from (above statement)
join ....
where....
```

I don't know how of if a @temp,joins, union... can be inside other select.

OR only thing I can do is create a @Temp2 inserting with first statement result and then work with other join,where... ?

**UPDATE 1:**

I also trying:

```
With cte (query returned columns)
as
(same query I was using to build my @temp as before)

(select ... from cte
join tblA
where...)
UNION
(select ... from cte
join tblB
where...)
```

But Im stuck at same point in how to perform other joins, where... with above total result

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking this through procedurally (first I'll get this set of answers, then I'll do some more work on them, then I'll do more work on that result). That doesn't tend to product the best results. What you need to try to do is write a single query that expresses *what you want*, and then let the `server` work our *how to do it*. One way to break your query down somewhat, but to keep it as one query, is to use [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). I'd recommend those over using temp tables.

Comment: tnks, Im trying to use cte but see my question update1

Comment: So now you create a second CTE containing the `UNION` and then just use that CTE in your query and do joins to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can do it without temp-table:

```
WITH myCTE [ ( column_name [,...n] ) ]
AS
( here you define your query )
```

and after that you just do your Select but use CTE

```
Select ... from myCTE
join ....
where....
```

about CTE you can read [Here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/sql-server-cte-basics/)
**After Update**

```
Select fields from myCTE join table1
Union
Select fields from myCTE join table2
```

Without brackets in your query

Comment: pls see my update1 on question. I was able to return same as using @temp, but stuck at same point

Comment: now i managed to do. removed the brackets an include my new select between cte definition and the union. so: with cte as select ..from (select join union select join) as Tba where tba. xxx = ..... .  thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Create @temp
Select ...inser...into @temp where ...

;with temp2 as
(
    select ... from @temp Join tblA where ...
    UNION
    Select ... from @temp join tblB where ... 
)
select ... from temp2
join ....
where....
```